# Locking Frames Per Second to 60fps

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi, frame-rate

I saw this episode from Extra Credits on FPS and they mention that you should normally lock the fps to multiples of 30 because it matches up with the monitor's refresh rates and reduces artifacts. My code is running at 60fps but I'm still getting a very subtle artifacts in the movement.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zL5kOyHWI_E

It's in Windows Forms so perhaps there's really nothing to be done about it.

My render loop looks like this:

```
private void Render() {
    Update();
    if (RenderDelegate != null)
        RenderDelegate(_renderFunctions);
    var msPause = 1000 / (double)FpsLimit - _gameTime.DeltaTime;
    if (msPause > 0)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)msPause);
    _attachedSystem.NextFrame(); // Will call Invalidate();
}
```

Implemtation in the WinForms control

```
protected void FormOnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs paintEventArgs) {
    _graphic = paintEventArgs.Graphics;
    _render();
}
void IGameMessages.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect) {
    _graphic.DrawImage(image, rect);
}
void IGameMessages.NextFrame() {
    Control.Invalidate();
}
```

I'm guessing that sleeping by a dynamic value is not the preferred way because it might be like 1% out of sync with the monitor refresh rate or something? The fps output swings between 58 to 63 fps (There probably something wrong with the DeltaTime calculations too)

Comment: And a disclaimer: I've put this line in the form already
 SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.Opaque | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true); The artifacts I'm getting is VERY subtle. And only in "feeling" of the movement.

Comment: Making a 60fps game in Winforms is already a loosing battle. You have many many more things to worry about before you get to the 60fps issue the video talks about. You really should be using a framework designed to to do game development, not try to shoehorn it in to winforms, you will get many benefits like hardware acceleration.

Comment: WinForms would never be my personal choice either. I'm working on a 10 year old project and the boss wants to embed a little mini game into the application. But yeah I'd bet on Unity. Perhaps the right answer is alternatives? There is a few requirements. 1st: The application is hosted inside windows forms (Not necessarily painted by). 2nd: I can't install any software on the client machine but I can use as many dll's as i would like.

Comment: Synching with the monitor simply is not built-in with winforms, alas. WPF will do it out of the box though..

Comment: I read a few places you could use XNA or OpenGL. But it would require some kind of "Canvas" to slap inside as a control in WinForms.

Comment: Directly accessing the video adapter, and thus cause tearing artifacts, is over and done with for the past 10 years.  Now you render to a surface in memory and the DWM composits it to the screen.  It has been a long time since I've seen anybody complain about tearing, is this an XP question?

Comment: Ok i know at this point some SO captain is gonna nuke the question for being nonconstructive. I don't have tearing artifacts. I know in the video that's what they mention. What i have is a weak Jitter in movement. Might be caused to the DeltaTime getting hiccups or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForm is not ideal. The reason is that screen updates are not depending your app. There is no screen interupt in WinForms.

I kept a timer and moved an object from left to right, 800 pixels, the "sprite" alike object had a start counter integer. Depending on how much time had past a new position was taken.

```
if(!x.AtEnd) {
    X.DeltaTime = X.Startime-currentTime;
    int x = myStartTime - currentTime;
    x.position = X.DeltaTime % 430; //time was in ms and 430 just a number 

    if (x.postion > x.end) {
        x.position=x.end;
        x.AtEnd=true;
    }
}
```

It depended a bit on the number how fast it moved and how well it looked (which depends on computer speed as well, as slower computers take more time to execute on other threads as well). Using something like above I got a reasonable smooth moving object, not as smooth as in games, but it worked well and there was no blocking (Delaying) code in it (as I tried with thread delays so each movement took equal time, but that didn't got smooth either, the screen update is too random for that)

Comment: It's a long time since i left that company, but thanks for the answer anyway. 2 years later i came to the understanding that i should be using callbacks or thread locks provided by the framework, which may be provided by the hardware.